# The OP posted a potential answer to this question as a comment

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

The OP posted a potential answer to this question as a comment and left it at that.

[Data-Node Does Not Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085978/data-node-does-not-start)

Based on his comment, I investigated my own issue and was able to resolve my issue which seems very similar to his issue. I have added a comment asking him to convert his comment to an answer. Is there anything more I can do?

Comment: If they don't post an answer, please make sure you post an answer. It will help people in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can post an answer to the question that answers the question.

Make sure you appropriately cite any work that is not your own (for example, a comment on the question providing information you needed to write your answer).

Comment: sounds reasonable.